# How can I deploy a node-red app in IBM Cloud?

Tags: ibm-cloud, node-red

recently IBM has upgrade the Node-Red resource, and now it can't be deployed as before, how can I deploy my nodes? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The old Node-RED boilerplate template has been replaced by a new Starter Kit option in the catalog.

A guide to deploying the new starter kit is available here:

https://developer.ibm.com/tutorials/how-to-create-a-node-red-starter-application/